# Creating a fillable form for Telegram

Tags: forms, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am looking to create a fillable form for a Telegram channel, where people follow a link to the channel, and then they are asked to fill out a form. From there the admins are given the information that was filled out and they can verify whether or not the person should be allowed to join the channel. This is mostly so that I can keep the community from being overloaded with people who are only there to troll.

I've been looking into different types of bots for Telegram, but I have yet to find one that actually has a form submission aspect to it, along with a verification process. Is this something that I am going to have to build myself? If so, would anybody be able to point me in the right direction so that I can figure out what I am doing? I'm not entirely versed on how to build a bot or a program like this, but if I had enough resources then I would be able to figure it out no problem

Thanks in advance.